# Database connectivity pgm error-apps has stopped force close

Tags: android, android-emulator

My `xml`

```
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
android:hint="input" android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"> 
android:id="@+id/senddata" android:layout_height="wrap_content"android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Button"> android:id="@+id/textView1"   android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

error

```
08-09 10:46:38.736: W/dalvikvm(337): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560) 
08-09 10:46:38.816: E/AndroidRuntime(337): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
08-09 10:46:38.816: E/AndroidRuntime(337): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity  ComponentInfo{com.example.dbconnectivity/com.example.dbconnectivity.Database}:

java.lang.InstantiationException: com.example.dbconnectivity.Database 
08-09 10:46:38.816: E/AndroidRuntime(337): android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569) 08-09   0:46:38.816: E/AndroidRuntime(337):
```